# Linked Microsoft database server login failed

Tags: login, database

A query being executed on a SQL Server instance that makes use of a linked server is currently failing due to the error : Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON
How would i troubleshoot this issue

Comment: What does the ERRORLOG says?, you can use this sql script to check it:
`USE MASTER`
`GO`
`EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Logging SQL Server messages in file'`
`GO`